# Hiding an element in an Azure AD B2C user flow

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have a default reset password flow. At one step, there is a frame that looks like the below image:
[image: Image of a user flow, with input forms and buttons.]

**How can I hide the blue button in the middle, the one with "Change e-mail"? Is it possibly to inject a few lines of CSS somewhere?**

Comment: You cannot add CSS code inside the button through User Flow, but you can do it with Custom Flow and also you can create custom page, check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-user-flow)